# New Fragment not fully replace the old fragment

Tags: android-fragments, replace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWKwn.jpg)

this is the layout after i click my image button,the new fragment not fully replace the old fragment...

this is my old fragment menu java code

```
public class CMenu extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cmenu,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);
    initView(view);

}
private void initView(View view){
    ImageButton prebtn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.premium_cake);
    prebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton homemade = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.homemade);
    homemade.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton sc_cake = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sc_cake);
    sc_cake.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton special_food = (ImageButton) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.special_food);
    special_food.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton delicious_drink = (ImageButton) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.delicious_drink);
    delicious_drink.setOnClickListener(this);
    ImageButton other = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.other);
    other.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.premium_cake:

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MenuFragment,new 
PremiumCake()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.homemade:

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MenuFragment,new 
HomeMade()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.sc_cake:

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MenuFragment,new 
SpecialCake()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.delicious_drink:

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MenuFragment,new 
DeliciousDrink()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.special_food:

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MenuFragment,new 
SignatureFood()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.other:

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MenuFragment,new 
 Other()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
    }
}

this is my new fragment java code

public class Other extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.other, container, false);
}
```

old fragment xml (i am using scroll view on this )

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MenuFragment"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:id="@+id/MenuFragment">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sc_cake"
        android:background="@drawable/sc_bg"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/homemade"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/premium_cake"
        android:background="@drawable/pc_bg"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/homemade"
        android:background="@drawable/hmc_bg"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/premium_cake"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/delicious_drink"
        android:background="@drawable/dd_bg"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/special_food"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/other"
        android:background="@drawable/other_bg"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/delicious_drink"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/special_food"
        android:background="@drawable/sf_bg"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sc_cake"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

new fragment xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

<GridLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#2e3192">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cb_big"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/coolerbag_big" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cb_small"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/coolerbag_small" />


    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please, enter the code you wrote to replace the fragment

Comment: i am sorry because this is my first time post on strackoverflow. The code i am updated on my post

Comment: You gave Fragment itself as a Container, you need the id of the layout that contains the fragment. I will upload the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> XML of Activity that contains old Fragment

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

> The replace method removes the previous fragment that was in the
>   container and adds a new one.

So, in your Activity Class where you have initially loaded old fragment, you must have done:

```
OldFragment fragment = new OldFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

So now, to replace the old fragment with a new one when image is clicked, instead of:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MenuFragment,new 
PremiumCake()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Just do:

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new 
    PremiumCake()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

> container is the Frame layout in the Activity's XML  which was holding
>   your old fragment and replaces it by new Fragment.

Comment: Happy to help :)